# ClassCastException using Class.cast using Generics

Tags: java, class, generics, casting, classcastexception

I am writing a generic method which will validate a property by trying a class.cast on it but I keep getting a ClassCastException

... Class to Test

```
public <T> T get(Properties p, String propKey, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {

    T val = null;

    Object propValue = p.get(propKey);

    if(propValue== null) {
        throw new Exception("Property (" + propKey + ") is null");
    }

    try {
        val = clazz.cast(propValue); // MARKER

    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Property (" + propKey + ") value is invalid value of type (" + clazz + ")", e);
    }



    return val;
}
```

... Test Class

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    propUtil = new PropUtil();
    properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("test.int.prop", "3");
}

@Test
public void testGet() {

    try {

        assertEquals(new Integer(3), propUtil.get(properties, "test.int.prop", Integer.class));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

The code at commented at MARKER is causing the ClassCastException.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your replies.  I realise the basic act of casting from String to Integer wasn't possible.  I was just trying to make the method slicker and do the conversion check for me.  I've just worked out the solution I was lookin using Reflection which is :

```
    Object propValue = p.get(propKey);
    Constructor<T> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(String.class);
    val = constructor.newInstance(propValue);
```

i.e Using the public constructor that takes the String.class (i.e. the String property value)

Works a treat.

Comment: Nice workaround, and if there is no constructor with that signature a [NoSuchMethodException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodException.html) is thrown witch you seem to handle in your code.

Answer (score 3):

The `Properties` class is a `Hashtable` stores `String` objects, especially when you call `setProperty`.  You have added the `String` "3", not the integer `3`.  You are effectively attempting to cast "3" as an `Integer`, so that correctly throws a `ClassCastException`.  Try

```
assertEquals("3", propUtil.get(properties, "test.int.prop", String.class));
```

Or if you *want* to have `get` return an `Integer`, then just use a `Hashtable<String, Integer>`, or even better, use a `HashMap<String, Integer>`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Properties` here is `java.util.Properties`, the values are always `String`s.

You should use the `getProperty()` method, rather than the `get()` method that happens to be visible from `HashTable` because this class was written back when the Java folks were less careful about composition versus inheritance.

Comment: Yes.  They are always String but the properties will contain String, Integers and Doubles so I want the generic method to do the conversion and throw an exception if the actual value is not assignable the class.

Answer (score 1):

This Line

```
properties.setProperty("test.int.prop", "3");
```

puts a `java.lang.String` in properties

and You pass `Integer.class` to you generic method. So the `ClassCastException` is expected!

If you want to Test for `Integer.class` you have to put an Integer

```
properties.put("test.int.prop", 3);
```

Note in the above line the use of [put](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#put%28K,%20V%29) since the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class is extending [Hashtable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

If your intention is to put a `String`  and test for an `Integer` then you have to somehow [parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) that String to an Integer value

Comment: The `setProperty` method takes a `String` for the value, not an `int`.